# Table row background based on the day of the week

Tags: angular, date, datatables

I have a table what goes from angular. The table contains two columns, one with dates, and one with the day of the week. My goal is to color the lines green if the day falls on a weekend. Thanks for the help :)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let day of days">
<tr [ngStyle]="{'background-color': day.mydate | date:'EEEE' === 'Sunday' ? 'green' : 'white' }">
<td>{{day.id}}</td>
<td>{{day.mydate  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
<td>{{day.mydate | date:'EEEE' }}</td>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript get day function to determine the day of the week..
As you want to color sundays your code should look like this..

HTML-

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let day of days">
<tr 
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': day.mydate.getDay() == 0 ? 'green' : 'white' }">
<td>{{day.id}}</td>
<td>{{day.mydate  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
<td>{{day.mydate | date:'EEEE' }}</td>
</tr>
</ng-container>
```

Component: -

```
export class AppComponent {
  public days: {id:number; mydate: Date;}[] =[{id:1, mydate:new Date(2019,10,10)}];

}
```

more about getday function:- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_getday.htm